# How to find triple integral of the following question?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

$$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{6}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} xyz\sqrt{2-y^2-x^2}\mathbb dx\,\mathbb dy\,\mathbb dz$$

I've been trying to solve that question and over and over again, I get answer of:

$$-\left(\dfrac49\right)(-1)^{\frac32}$$

Where as the online integral solver gives an answer of:

$$\dfrac{2(1-1156i\sqrt{34}+1225i\sqrt{35})}{15}$$

I am really confused that If I am correct or the online integral is?

Comment: Can you show *how* you ended up with a value of $-\left(\frac{4}{9}\right)(-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}$?

Comment: Are you sure that the integral bounds are correct? $\int_6^1$ looks suspicious, and causes the radicand to be negative. Perhaps is should be $\int_0^1$ for both $x$ and $y$?

Comment: It is not a good solver if it leaves the answer complex for the real integral. P.S. Though if one takes $y=6$ into account it may explain the trouble. Change $y=6$ to $y=0$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: This site should include embedded maths keyboard in posting section...

Answer (score 1):

Notice, $$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{6}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} xyz\sqrt{2-y^2-x^2}dxdydz$$ 
$$=\int_{0}^{2}\int_{6}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{1} x\sqrt{2-y^2-x^2}dx\right) yzdydz$$  $$=\int_{0}^{2}\int_{6}^{1}\left[\frac{-2(2-y^2-x^2)^{3/2}}{3}\right]_{0}^{1}yzdydz$$ $$=\frac{2}{3}\int_{0}^{2}\int_{6}^{1}\left[-(1-y^2)^{3/2}+(2-y^2)^{3/2}\right]yzdydz$$ $$=\frac{2}{3}\int_{0}^{2}\left(\int_{6}^{1}y\left[(2-y^2)^{3/2}-(1-y^2)^{3/2}\right]dy\right)zdz$$ $$=\frac{2}{3}\int_{0}^{2}\left[-\frac{2}{5}(2-y^2)^{5/2}+\frac{2}{5}(1-y^2)^{5/2}\right]_{6}^{1}zdz$$ $$=\frac{2}{3}\int_{0}^{2}\left[-\frac{2}{5}+0+\frac{2}{5}(-34)^{5/2}-\frac{2}{5}(-35)^{5/2}\right]zdz$$ $$=\frac{4}{15}(-1+1156i\sqrt{34}-1225i\sqrt{35})\int_{0}^{2}zdz$$ $$=\frac{4}{15}(1156i\sqrt{34}-1225i\sqrt{35}-1)\left[\frac{z^2}{2}\right]_{0}^{2}$$ $$=\frac{4}{15}(1156i\sqrt{34}-1-1225i\sqrt{35})\left[\frac{(2)^2}{2}-0\right]$$ $$=\frac{8}{15}(1156i\sqrt{34}-1-1225i\sqrt{35})$$
that is the correct answer